# Cannot find the program file directory for Civilization IV

Tags: windows-7, gaming

I did a thorough search of Program Files, Program Files (x86), and AppData, and couldn't find the program file directory for Civilization IV.

Here's where it gets weird. All of the shortcuts to the game, either the target field is empty, or it *leads back to itself*. WTF is this? The "show in folder" also only gives me a folder containing the shortcut.

Out of ideas. Guessing the folder is hidden, but I have "view hidden files and folders" enabled.

I explicitly recall installing Civilization IV (from a purchased disc, so it's a legitimate version) in the default install path. I have no idea why it's not showing up in the default install path.

Also the game is running perfectly fine (from any of the shortcuts).

Is there any other way for me to pinpoint the install directory?

Answer (score 1):

Find out the process ID of the game when it's running by opening a command prompt and doing "tasklist".

Once you have the PID of the game, say it was 1340, run this at a cmd prompt

wmic process where processid=1340 list full

that will show you, among other things, the full path and command line that was used to launch the executable

Answer (score 1):

You can open Task Manager, right-click on the process name, and select **Open file location**.

[image: Task Manager]